# RadGridView Enter Key Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I have a winform application that contain a radgridview. Only one cell is set to enable editing. The remaining cells are read only.  I have several radgridview event handle that perform different  computation. When I'm editing a cell and hit the tab key it jump to the next cell(perfect).  My problem is when I hit the "Enter" key, it throw a sort of infinite loop error.  How can I disable the "Enter" key or change the behavior to mimic the tab key function?  I  try the below but it doesn't catch the "Enter" key action.  I was reading  that the enter key triggers functionality in our Grid (end edit, move to next row, etc.),

```
     private void radGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

        }
    }
```

Comment: are you familiar with the `e.Handled = true;` method

Comment: check this link out if you are wanting to use Enter Key to tab to next cell - https://morecoding.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/enter-key-as-tab-key-in-datagridview/

Comment: I tried the e.Handled = true and that didn't work.  It seem like the Enter key doesn't even trigger the KeyDown event.

Comment: do a google search on KeyDown event and Return key as Tab Key.. there are actually lots of different working examples on how to get this to work online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the  problem by re-coding my codes.  I had two cell value that get updated on the CellValueChanged event. I move the updated code to the CellEditEnd event.